# The English of/English of someone

Tags: definite-article

> The English of my friends is so-so.
>
> English of my friends is so-so.

I think it should be "the English" but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is more correct than the second, but it would be much more idiomatic to say

> My friends' English is [only] so-so.